# How to download a file and pass it to a function

Tags: python

I have a function that requires a base64 encoded file.
I can download and **save** this file using;

```
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"}) 
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
with open('file.torrent', "wb") as code:
        code.write(f.read())
```

But I don't want to save it, I want to pass it to a function.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: I get, "'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc6 in position 788"

Comment: You have a function that requires a base64 encoded file, path to a file or string?

Comment: It's a module called transmissionrpc, I'm trying to pass it a .torrent file, without saving the .torrent file to disk. The docs say that it will accept a base 64 encoded torrent data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to pass a file like object, you can write  the base64 encoded string to a `io.BytesIO` object:

```
import requests
from io import BytesIO
f = BytesIO()
r = requests.get("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34372102/how-to-download-a-file-and-pass-it-to-a-function")

f.write(r.content.encode("base_64"))

f.seek(0)

print(f.read())
```

Output:

```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 ..................................................
```

Pass `f` straight to your function. If you just have to pass an encoded string just pass `r.content.encode("base_64")` or `f.read().encode("base_64")` using `urllib2`.

If it needs to have a `.torrent` extension you can write to a `NamedTemporaryFile` and pull the name with `f.name`:

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
f = NamedTemporaryFile("wb+",suffix=".torrent")
r = requests.get("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34372102/how-to-download-a-file-and-pass-it-to-a-function")

print(f.name)
f.write(r.content.encode("base_64"))
f.seek(0)

/tmp/tmpzedDPm.torrent
```

You can pass the file object, or `f.name` to your function as the function will be able to use the file with just f.name.

```
with open(f.name) as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Comment: Does this work with python2.7? Requests not importing, have installed it with pip but im getting `descriptor 'write' requires a '_io.BytesIO' object but received a 'str' `

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: Thanks! I had already been using urllib2, so `f.read().encode("base_64")` worked. Massively appreciate your help.